# Change font in MS SQL Management Studio Database Diagram

Tags: fonts, sql-server-2008

My eyes must be getting old as viewing database diagrams is getting more difficult every year.  Is there a way to change font type and/or increase the font size of text in database diagrams?  I've already tried looking making changes under Tools > Options > Fonts and Color, but it seems to make little difference.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SQL 2008 version of the Management Studio there is a Zoom feature the Diagrams.  And yeah, from my experience, changing the fonts for "Tables and Diagrams" doesn't seem t have any affect on THOSE diagrams.  Go figure. :)

On Windows 7 I can Ctrl-MouseWheel to zoom in and out, and you can pick a zoom level via the `Database Diagram-->Zoom` on the menu bar.

There's also a zoom level drop down available if the Database Diagram toolbar is showing.

Comment: Actually, the font changes I made for "tables and diagrams" did kick in.  It apparently involved restarting the management studio, but it did work.  Strange.

Comment: @Andy Evans - Good to know!  The couple times I tried, I always changed them back after they seemed to do nothing when applied. :)

Answer (score 1):

Does it make little difference or no difference? Have you tried Large Fonts in the operating system display controls?

Answer (score 1):

You may also be looking for a way to change the results of "edit top 200 rows" which now (to me) seems to be two or three pixels smaller than it used to -- probably my eyes:)

Note that the text editor, the most obvious choice, and the one that used to control this, no longer controls this in SQL 2005+ - it just controls it in New Query window 
Use Tools/Options select environment/fonts and colors then use the drop-down to select  Data Viewer. Then pick your font, say OK and restart.

Apparently there's no way to separate the "editor" portion (above) from the results (below) (although you can scroll the size using your Ctrl/ mouse wheel, it does not "stick" after a submit)

They both need to be in the same font (Bad Microsoft! Bad! No desert for you!)